# Can we use wait and notify on class level object? And how it behaves?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I know wait and notify are used for monitors to indicate wait nd notify for different threads.
But I am confused what happens if we use wait and notify on class level monitor -

Example:
Object classLock = ClassA.class;

classLock.wait() and classLock.notify().

Can we use this way?

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: Yes you can use it that way.